# Show message in media-new.php

Tags: hooks, attachments, notices

I'm wondering if there's a way to show a specific message when user uploads a file using the `wp-admin/media-new.php` script.

So far I have this:

```
function my_uploads_notice(){
    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow == 'media-new.php' ) {
         echo '<div class="error">
             <p><h4>MY NOTICE</h4></p>
         </div>';
    }
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'my_uploads_notice');
```

Comment: Please show us your efforts - it's a prerequisite to asking questions. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there's a way, research within [this results](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=admin_notice). If not a solution, you'll find a starting poing.

Comment: I've added the code I'm currently using. 
Thanks to @brasofilo I've limited the notice to only show on the media-new.php

Comment: @pangi, is that a solution? If so, please add your own Answer in the box bellow.

Comment: @brasofilo, it's not, but it's the closest I've managed to get

Comment: Well, I tested the snippet and it *does show* the notice in the `media-new.php` screen. Please, try to make the Question as clear as possible. Where are you using the code? What result you get? Any error messages? [Debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) information?